# if statement of mysql in text file of .sql executed by batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file, if-statement

I'd like first introduce my requirement. I have a batch file which will execute a Textfile of sql. And I need the function that the program will first check the count of a table, if it is 0, then insert rows.
   In the following is my code.
   I was told error:

```
RROR 1064 (42000) at line 15: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
nnear 'IF @a>0
THEN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `martin1` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES (1, 'aaa'),(' at line 1
```

Allthough I have tried some other ways such as adding ";",deleting ";", but it still does not work.

```
SET @a=(SELECT count(*) FROM `martin1`);
IF @a>0 
THEN 
INSERT IGNORE INTO `martin1` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES (1, 'aaa'),(2, 'bbb');
END IF;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error, because you can't use control structures such as `if` or `while` in a normal query. They can only be used in stored procedures or functions. In this case you'd need a procedure. Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc_name()
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM marting1) THEN
  INSERT IGNORE INTO `martin1` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES (1, 'aaa'),(2, 'bbb');
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then execute the procedure with this statement:

```
CALL my_proc_name();
```

Note, that I replaced your `COUNT(*)` with `EXISTS()`. It's faster, cause it stops as soon as an entry is found, while `COUNT()` continues till it's finished counting every row.

Comment: hi.thank u very much for ur kindness reply. but i was told told in the query "CALL my_proc_name()",here is the content of my text file of .sql:            CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `martintest` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `martintest`;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `martin1` (
  `col1` int(11) default NULL,
  `col2` text
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CALL my_proc_name();

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc_name()
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `martin1`) THEN
  INSERT IGNORE INTO `martin1` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES (1, 'aaa'),(2, 'bbb');
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: or do u mean the stored procedure should only be in the database,not in a text file? thank u

Comment: Yes, the procedure needs to be in the database. You execute the procedure before you created it in your text file. Add `drop procedure if exists my_proc_name;` before `create procedure...` and the `call my_proc_name();` after that.